# \abs produces "undefined control structure" error

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm getting an `Undefined control structure` error when I use `\abs`, even for a simple term like `\abs{x}`.

I'm using `pdflatex` and the `amsmath` package in math mode `$ $`. I've also tried deleting `.aux` files.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `\abs` macro is not predefined by most math-related packages I'm familiar with. However, it may easily be defined via `\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}`. This definition assumes implicitly that the macro will be used in math mode only.

Comment: Always adding the `\left/right` is not a good idea in general, see my answer.

Comment: the `\abs` command was defined in an *example* file distributed with ams document classes.  unfortunately, instead of reading the instructions and using the designated template files to launch documents, many people start with the example file, rip (some) things out and put in their own material.  this has led to many problems, and not just for authors.  ams author packages are being revamped, and the definition of `\abs` will go away.  it was *only an example*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not every conceivable mathematical operator has been defined in advance. So you neeed to define it. Here is my usual method:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

Then `\abs{x} = \lvert x \rvert`, `\abs*{x}=\left\lvert x \right\rvert` and say `\abs[\big]{x} = \bigl\lvert x \bigr\rvert`.

In recent projects I've extended it a bit with

```
\usepackage{mathtools,etoolbox}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\abs}[1]{\lvert}{\rvert}{\ifblank{#1}{{}\cdot{}}{#1}}
```

Then one can write `\abs{}: \mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)` and `\abs{}` will added a centered dot to indicate an empty argument.

Addition: Here's an example of why it's not always a good idea to autoscale:

[image]

Comment: To be honest both last two examples look wrong to me about their vertical extent.

Comment: that's strange concerning the amsmath package. i was 'sure' that abs was pre-defined. thx. | was currently used because it was only a short (absolute value) term. your hint will be used the next time. :-)

Comment: @percusse: in which manner? I usually use the following rule: It should be clear to the reader what the fences enclose, but the fences should not be so large that they dominate the expression. In the later there is not much reason to left the `|`'s extend further down.

Comment: I see your argument however, I think they should enclose the index constraints (like the first one without the top excess) otherwise it looks (at least to me) like a misplaced index constraint for the whole abs value.  I tend to smash the operator inside the delimiters.

Comment: Exactly how would you do that? `\smash[b]` on the sum with limits leaves the fences the same size as on the right in the image. No symetric fences end up looking strange IMO.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't see this. Well, my quick experiment with `mathtools` : `\abs[\Bigg]{\mathop{ \sum_{\substack{1 \le i \le 10\\ 1 \le j \le 5}}^\infty x^{i} y^{j}}}` which is almost OK for me but I would even make it a little longer to get the other constraint too.